# URI path in WPF window background image

Tags: wpf, uri

I'm trying to assign a background to my WPF window.
I have a .jpg in bin\debug\StoredData\wallpaper.jpg
(I want to obtain the .jpg from there).

I came to putting this code inside the .cs file (newly created file):

```
     InitializeComponent();
        ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
        myBrush.ImageSource =
             new BitmapImage(new Uri("\\StoredData\\login_wallpaper.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
        this.Background = myBrush;
```

But I get a "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined" message.
What should I change?

Comment: The image file should be an assembly resource and loaded by a Resource File Pack URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\StoredData\login_wallpaper.jpg` is a relative URI. You can either change the `UriKind` to `UriKind.Relative`, or enter an absolute URI, depending on what behavior you want.